# Why does int main() { return main(); } cause stackoverflow and not tail recursion?

Tags: c, gcc, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

Compiled this on Windows using GCC. It crashed immediately with `Exception Code:  c00000fd`.

Edit : Tried compiling following code (for visible output) and it causes stackoverflow.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("Hello World\n");
return main();
}
```

Output -

```
>gcc trailORoverflow.c -o trailORoverflow.exe

Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

It keeps printing Hello World for sometime and crashes.

Edit: Didn't crash with `O2`, `O3` and `-O1 -foptimize-sibling-calls` optimizations.

Comment: Perhaps the correct answer has something to do with tail call recursion. iirc GCC will implement tail call recursion, i.e. optimizing away recursive calls, when possible

Comment: Because the C standard does not require a specific optimisation. (It does not even require using a stack for local variables). And use a correct prototype-style function declarator: `main(void)`.

Comment: it definitely makes sense to try gcc with different optimization flags and probably some combination will give you infinite loop you want

Comment: gcc or g++ ? Then there can be a difference.

Comment: Use `-O2`, `-O3`, or `-O1 -foptimize-sibling-calls`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It worked! I tried with all optimizations you suggested and it didn't cause stackoverflow. Why did it cause stackoverflow the first time?

Comment: gcc doesn't perform tail recursion optimization by default, possibly because it makes programs harder to debug and unwind after exceptions. So your unoptimized program used up a bit of stack space every time it did a call (`callq main` followed by `push   %rbp`), until it reached the limit imposed by the OS. An optimized program would do something like `jmp   main`. I don't have gcc on Windows so can't provide a comprehensive answer, but someone else will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown will call `main` infinitely, and therefore will result a stack overflow. This is true in the case of any function and not specific to main. Each function call a stack frame is created in memory, and as infinite such frames is created as the recursion goes deep, you get a stackoverflow.

But if you make a proper base termination like the example as follows, for recursive calls in `main` then there is an interesting thing.

```
int main (void)
{
  static int x = 100;

  if (x == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  x--;
  printf ("%d\n", x);
  main ();
  return 0;
}
```

There is a difference in calling `main` recursively in C and C++ Language, and I think it is interesting to point that out. Here is a [post](https://phoxis.org/2012/10/06/c-qa-4-calling-main-recursively/) I wrote, I am giving some explanation about it.

C++ Standards talk about these in

Section 3.6.1 Paragraph 3

```
Recursive calls are permitted, except to the function named main.
```

and Section 5.2.2 Paragraph 9

```
The function main shall not be used within the program. … … …
```

I did not find any such restriction in the C standards. What I found about recursive calls in the C99 standards in Section 6.5.2.2 Paragraph 11 is as follows

```
Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain of other functions.
```

Therefore calling main recursively in C Language is deterministic. But as per C++ standards calling main from any function or recursively is not allowed.